# java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. titanium

Tags: android, titanium, android-appcompat

I'm creating a custom theme for my Titanium application using this theme [generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/). But when I run my application it's crashing and my log says that I need `appCompact` even if I set the theme for sdk > sdk 11.

And my targeting Android version is API 19 and min SDK version is API14, so I wonder why I need `appCompact`.

This is what my log says:

```
 [ERROR] :  TiApplication: (main) [512,512] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.s/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.; Titanium 3.4.0,2014/09/25 16:42,b54c467
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.s/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(Activ
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:108)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.onCreate(TiBaseActivity.java:516)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity.onCreate(TiActivity.java:18)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   ... 11 more
```

Comment: can you provide your `tiapp.xml` and the path where you put your generated theme.

Comment: <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <tool-api-level>14</tool-api-level>
        <manifest>
            <application android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Light"/>
            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
            <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
        </manifest>
    </android>

Comment: appname/platform/android/res/values

Comment: what is the `parent` value in your `@style/Light` ( would be at appname/platform/android/res/values/styles.xml )

Comment: the `parent` in Light theme should be like `<style name="Light" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using an `ActionBarActivity`, which requires an AppCompat theme. I'm not sure how you'd do this with Titanium, but you'd either need to switch to an AppCompat theme or use a regular `Activity` (which shouldn't be a problem if you're targeting 11 or above).

Comment: @reegan29 do any of your themes declare that the `ActionBar` shouldn't be shown?

Comment: This is my question bro ..Can you answer this ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437690/how-to-get-wifilist-using-getter-from-standalone-class-extends-broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 9):

ok please try this,

Add this attribute to your activity

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

Answer (score 4):

write the code in style-v11 folder

```
 name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

and  in styles-v14 folder

```
 name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

Comment: can you add an explanation to this answer please?

Answer (score 4):

Simply change the ActionBarActivity to Activity or FragmentActivity

Answer (score 4):

I know it's very only question but you should include parent theme into your style.

```
   <!-- Base application theme. Transparent theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>


    <style name="Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit embarrassing to admit how I've encountered this error, but in a hope to save someone an hour or hair pulling - for me it was a stray ">" that I mistakenly copied into my `AndroidManifest`:

```
   <application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/my_backup_rules">
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon_l"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:requiredForAllUsers="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">
```

Too easy to miss if you have a very large manifest - the compiler doesn't complain.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all the styles in the library project.
Specify Style folder only in main project not in library project.
It worked for me :)