# Android Studio - Unfortunately. Application Has Stopped

Tags: android

I'm relatively new to android programming and am trying to run the application on a device but keep getting returned with the above message on the device that the application has stopped. I've been searching around trying all sorts of different fixes but it's supposedly unique to my code, this is the errors returned in the log:

**EDIT**

```
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chris.myapplication/com.example.chris.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67: Error inflating class <unknown>
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:268)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1837)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at com.example.chris.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    ... 11 more
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    ... 24 more
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:531)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:506)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:358)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1939)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:85)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:81)
 04-23 12:24:09.609: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):    ... 27 more
 04-23 12:24:09.639: I/ActivityManager(350): Process com.google.android.apps.maps:FriendService (pid 6260) has died.
 04-23 12:24:09.669: W/ActivityManager(350):   Force finishing activity com.example.chris.myapplication/.MainActivity
```

Originally the problem seemed to be with the theme, but now I'm being returned with different errors once I had fixed the theme problem. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity) seems to address the same issue

Comment: I had similar issue, Try to replace ActionBarACtivity with Activity.

Comment: Check these answers :

1)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063395/actionbarcompat-java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcom 

3)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689279/java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-des

Comment: Do you inherit from Activity in your class?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I changed the ActionBarActivity with Activity and it seems to have gotten ridden of that particular error, however, I still have the same problem with new errors that I updated in the OP

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below line

```
 parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

to your style .xml

OR

Add this attribute to your activity

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!